# R: Convert COO format matrix to regular matrix format

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a square matrix in a [COO (Coordinate list)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29) format.

For example:

```
From  To   Value
1     1     1
1     2     1
2     1     0
2     2     1
```

I want to convert it into regular R matrix format.
So it will look like this:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   1    1
[2,]   0    1
```

Please advise how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way I found:

Using [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf) package.

First, the table from the example:

```
> coo_mat <- rbind(c(1,1,1), c(1,2,1), c(2,1,0), c(2,2,1))
> coo_mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    1
[3,]    2    1    0
[4,]    2    2    1
```

Now, make it regular format matrix:

```
> as.matrix(Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=coo_mat[,1], j=coo_mat[,2], x=coo_mat[,3]))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `xtabs` in base R, like this:

```
out <- xtabs(coo_mat[, 3] ~ coo_mat[, 1] + coo_mat[, 2])
out
#             coo_mat[, 2]
# coo_mat[, 1] 1 2
#            1 1 1
#            2 0 1
```

The result is an object of classes "xtabs" and "table".

```
class(out)
# [1] "xtabs" "table"
```

If you want to get rid of the `dimnames` and the other `attributes`, you can do the following:

```
`dim<-`(`attributes<-`(out, NULL), dim(out))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    0    1
```